# Node.js - sync vs async fs while using in docker (microservice architecture)

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a microservice (in docker swarm) that all needs to do is clean files from 1 folder and that's all

is it good in that case to use a sync function? 
I would like to.

1- find the folder size

2- run over all files and delete

and there is a cron that runs the flow every minute
so why do I need to use async? and not sync

is there any problem in this code? is it good that I wrapped with promise or because it sync so I don't need a promise?

for example :

```
function getTotal(){   
  let totalSize = 0;

      files.map(file => {
        totalSize += fs.statSync(file.path).size;
      });

      return totalSize;
}
```

for get all files :

```
   fs.readdirSync(dirPath).map(file => {
          const fileOrDir = fs.statSync(
            [dirPath, file].join('/')
            })
   );
```

remove :

```
  const unlink = util.promisify(
    fs.unlink
  );
  await unlink(filePath);
```

all the flow :

```
files = await service.getFiles(folderPath);
service.getTotal();
for(files){
   await this.removeFile(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is a cron that runs the flow every minute so why do I need to use async?

If this process is not doing anything else that requires responsiveness except cleaning up these files (no server listening for incoming connections), then `sync` I/O is just fine.  You can just use `unlinkSync()`.

FYI, if you did need to use non-blocking I/O there is no need to manually promisify `fs` module functions in node.js any more (even if you did want to use non-blocking APIs) because the `fs.promises` interface contains promise versions of most of the functions.